# How can I use the `graphql-scalars` package with `typegraphql`?

Tags: typescript, graphql, typegraphql

I would like to make use of the `graphql-scalars` package of the-guild.dev. However, I don't understand how I can integrate it with `typegraphql`. This is their quick start guide https://the-guild.dev/graphql/scalars/docs/quick-start which I will paste the main parts below:

```
//schema.graphql
scalar ScalarName
```

You can also import ready-to-use type definitions for scalars like below

```js
// or import specific typeDefs only with ES6 Import
import { ScalarNameTypeDefinition } from 'graphql-scalars';
// or import all typeDefs once with ES6 Import
import { typeDefs as scalarTypeDefs } from 'graphql-scalars';

const typeDefs = [
  ...scalarTypeDefs,
  // other typeDefs
];
// or
const typeDefs = [
  ScalarNameTypeDefinition,
  // other typeDefs
];
```

You can either import the specific scalar's resolvers or all of the resolvers once.

```js
// or import specific resolvers only with ES6 Import
import { ScalarNameResolver } from 'graphql-scalars';
// or import all resolvers once with ES6 Import
import { resolvers as scalarResolvers } from 'graphql-scalars';
```

Adding to the Root Resolver Map

```js
const myResolverMap = {
  ScalarName: ScalarNameResolver,
 
  Query: {
    // more stuff here
  },
 
  Mutation: {
    // more stuff here
  },
};
```

How can I adapt this logic to use it with `typegraphql`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since most of the scalars from `graphql-scalars` library are mapped to primitive types (`number`, `string`, `boolean`) you cannot use [`scalarsMap`](https://typegraphql.com/docs/scalars.html#custom-scalars) (automatically infer the association between the reflected property type and the scalar, no need for explicit type annotation). 
Therefore, whenever you want to use a custom scalar, you must explicitly use the type annotation (note that this is valid also for basic `GraphQL` scalars):

```
import { GraphQLID } from 'graphql';
import { GraphQLTimestamp, GraphQLNonEmptyString } from 'graphql-scalars';

@ObjectType()
class MyObj {
  // GraphQL scalar
  @Field(() => GraphQLID)
  id!: string

  // graphql-scalars scalar
  @Field(() => GraphQLTimestamp)
  createdAt!: Date;
}

@Resolver(MyObj)
class MyObjResolver {
  // graphql-scalars scalar
  hello(@Arg('name', () => GraphQLNonEmptyString) name: string) {
    return `Hello ${name}!`;
  }
}

/* ... */
```

See [example](https://github.com/carlocorradini/reCluster/blob/main/server/src/graphql/entities/User.ts#L45)